# How to run a different query based on the day of week

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

I have a program that autoruns with Windows scheduler.  This program runs a stored procedure which uses Yesterdays date, to run a query against our database to pull results from the previous day.  This query EXCLUDES a specific time period throughout the day as we do not care about those results.  However, we have different hours on Sunday, and would like to change the query for Sunday... Is there a way to query differently if it's a "Sunday"?  Below is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Open_Close_Report_1] AS
declare   @dtNow         datetime ,   @dtToday       datetime ,   @dtFrom        datetime ,   @dtThru        datetime ,   @dtExcludeFrom datetime ,   @dtExcludeThru datetime, @dtExcludeEOD datetime 
set @dtNow         = getdate() 
set @dtToday       = convert(datetime,convert(varchar,@dtNow,112),112) 
set @dtFrom        = dateadd(day,-1,@dtToday) -- start-of-day yesterday 
set @dtThru        = dateadd(ms,-3,@dtToday)  -- end-of-day yesterday (e.g., 2012-06-17 23:59:59.997) 
set @dtExcludeFrom = convert(datetime, convert(char(10),@dtFrom,120) + ' 05:30:00.000' , 120 ) 
set @dtExcludeThru = convert(datetime, convert(char(10),@dtFrom,120) + ' 06:15:00.000' , 120 ) 
set @dtExcludeEOD = convert(datetime, convert(char(10),@dtFrom,120) + ' 08:00:00.000' , 120 ) 


SELECT Store_Id , DM_Corp_Received_Date, Register_Transaction_Type 
FROM Register_Till_Count_Tb 
WHERE (Register_Transaction_Type    =  'SOD' and store_ID = '12345'
AND DM_Corp_Received_date     between @dtFrom        
and @dtThru   
AND DM_Corp_Received_date not between @dtExcludeFrom 
and @dtExcludeThru) or (Register_Transaction_Type = 'EOD' and Store_ID='12345'
AND DM_Corp_Received_date Between @dtFrom and @dtThru)
```

On Sunday the `@DTExclude` From will be 6:30 and `@dtexcludeThru` will be 7:15

Comment: have you considered using the SQL Server Agent, instead ? It might offer you more granularity & control.

Comment: You've got an awful lot of unnecessary date->string->date conversions going on in there. It's also usually better to use an *exclusive* end date and avoid `BETWEEN`, if you need to capture an entire day - this would also avoid future issues if you move to `datetime2` which has more precision available in the milliseconds part.

Comment: I can't, It's SQL Server 2000 and there is not an easy way to send email through the Server agent in 2000

Comment: The Datetime2 is not something we will move too... Also I need to EXCLUDE which is why there is the between and "not" between

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets do more of the maths keeping everything as datetimes (or ints) rather than mucking about with strings:

```
declare   @dtNow         datetime ,   @dtToday       datetime ,   @dtFrom        datetime ,   @dtThru        datetime ,   @dtExcludeFrom datetime ,   @dtExcludeThru datetime, @dtExcludeEOD datetime 
set @dtNow         = getdate() 
set @dtToday       = DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,@dtNow),0)
set @dtFrom        = dateadd(day,-1,@dtToday)

declare @Sunday int
set @Sunday = CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday,@dtFrom) = DATEPART(weekday,'20120805') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
set @dtExcludeFrom = DATEADD(minute,330 + @Sunday * 60,@dtFrom)
set @dtExcludeThru = DATEADD(minute,375 + @Sunday * 60,@dtFrom)
set @dtExcludeEOD = DATEADD(minute,480,@dtFrom)
```

And, in your query, rather than having:

```
column between @dtFrom and @dtThru
```

use:

```
column >= @dtFrom and column < @dtToday
```

Comment: you define '20120805' this will program will run 365 days a year... so a defined date of 1 sunday does not do me any good...

Comment: @Shmewnix - I'm checking whether the day of the week of `@dtFrom` is the same as the day of the week for 20120805 (a known Sunday). It avoids having to account for different `DATEFIRST` and language settings.

Comment: interesting... way of handling this. I like it. Let me play with it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`datename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) and [`datepart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) functions. You can use an `if` statement to perform different logic based on what the day is. When run on a Sunday, they will yield these results:

```
select datename(dw, getdate()) -- Sunday
select datepart(dw, getdate()) -- 1
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand good catch, that's what I get for copy/pasting one line to the other in a hurry..

Comment: "When run on a Sunday..." when the language is English, and `DATEFIRST` hasn't been set to a fruity value...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever based on the code in the question I assumed English was fine. I wasn't aware of `DATEFIRST`, I'll have to read up on that.