# Different select query based on the day of week? - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible to execute a different select query for each day of the week. I currently have the following columns: id, station_name, week_type and service.

The week_type is an enom value with the following options: 'Mon-Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Special'.

The service column only has a varchar value of the time of day. It needs to apply as the service operates the same on a weekly schedule depending on the week_type.

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
|               id                  |station_name| week_type |  service  |
+-----------------------------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
|               1                   | Station1   |  Mon-Thur |  08:15:00 |
|                                   |            |           |           |
|               2                   | Station2   |    Sat    |  10:15:00 |
+-----------------------------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

As seen in the table above, when it is Saturday in my timezone and is equal to the week_type, then it should only show Saturday rows. And etc. for the other columns.

Any help would be much appreciated, as I am new to SQL.

Comment: why wouldn't you determine what the "week_type" was at the application layer and pass it down to the query as a parameter?

Comment: Im not sure if this will help,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902495/how-to-run-a-different-query-based-on-the-day-of-week.

Comment: @Jesse, this is for SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

I think you really need to work out on the table. Why don't you normalize your table.

```
station_services

id|station_name

station_working_days

id|station_id|weekday_id|working_hours
```

If you dont want week days as seperate table then you can hardcode from 1 as sunday to saturday as 7

```
station_working_days

id|station_id|weekday|working_hours
```

By normalising you will get all the flexibility in future too.

In case if the stations all the time have the same working hours then use the following table normalisation so that it may help you.

```
station_services

id|station_name|working_hours


station_working_days

id|station_id|weekday_id
```